# move iOS apps from one developer account to another?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

We have released 2 version of app in `itunesconnect`.

One user using version 1 and another user using version 2.

I am going to transfer the version 2 from one account to another account.
version 1 will it work?

Comment: Both version are in same account or different developer account?? (In a same account both version cannot remain active. Only higher version can remain active) If both are in different developer accounts, then you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

No, if both versions are in same account. (check the status of version 1, probably it must be inactive and won't become active again, once you replace/upload a higher version of build and if it is active only then it will work.)

If both are in different developer accounts, then you can transfer. (In a same account, both version cannot remain active. Only higher version can remain active).

Note: You can't move single version of app from one to other account. You must move entire application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have few question can i create the chat with you??? please https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176053/app-transfer

Comment: Krunal and Bhavin Kansagara i have some question please join this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176760/app-transfer-chat\\

Comment: i release the app and remove from sale then can we do the app transfer??

Comment: krunal please see below answer and help me

Answer (score 1):

> As per your question, I think you are trying to ask, if the app with version 1, on existing user's device will keep on running or stop, once you move the app to other account?

if that is your question, then the answer will be YES, the apps with the version 1 on one user will keep on running. However, if you wants to move the application from one account to other then the whole app with all it's previous version information will be moved to new account.

Comment: Thanks Bhavin. i have one more question. Can we see the previous download count as well in new account?

Comment: Krunal and Bhavin Kansagara i have some question please join this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176760/app-transfer-chat\\

Comment: i release the app and remove from sale then can we do the app transfer??

Comment: Bhavin please see below answer and help me

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040906/warning-itms-9000-potential-loss-of-keychain-access/27324256 It explains everything. Read the important part in above link.

Answer (score 0):

@Krunal  and @Bhavin 
After App transfer i created the distribution and provisional certificate in new account.
and I tried to update it by uploading the newest version on application loader from new account. At the end, I received the following message:

Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['teamid1.com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['teamid2.com.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx']. This will result in a loss of keychain access.

What i do now??

Comment: See your steps: 

1. You transferred app to another account, it means - app (with existing identifier) is still alive on app store.

2. You are trying to upload same app with new identifier... so, it should show you an error.

Now, please let me know, Do you want a complete new app with new identifier or existing identifier?

Comment: i created the distribution and provisional  in new account and upload the ipa using new account i mean new identifier

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer... first you had transferred app (not create a new app) to another account. That may be reason for error.