# Future effects of Keychain Access and Push Notification Entitlement warning on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I received the following warnings when I am trying to update my iOS app with a new profile. I didn't have time to research so I ignored the warning and went ahead.

There are some threads about resolving these warnings, but what I wonder is that would there be any side effects to ignore these warnings? (e.g. Would something go terribly wrong in the current version or if I update my app again?)

My app requires camera, gallery and location access. Would keychain access warning have an adverse effect on these functionalities?

> **Potential Loss of Keychain Access** - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['removed'] and the
>   new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier
>   of ['removed']. This will result in a loss of keychain access. For
>   more information, please consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html
>
> **Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service,
>   but the app signature's entitlements do not include the
>   "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push
>   Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push
>   Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing
>   your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the
>   "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in
>   the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more
>   information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification
>   service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future
>   submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework,
>   you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the
>   API.  After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or
>   Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Would a professional ignore these warnings?

Comment: Well I'm not a professional, I develop apps as a hobby.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Identifier Entitlement Value has Changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792236/application-identifier-entitlement-value-has-changed)

Comment: how did you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions to fix the warnings you got:

**Potential Loss of Keychain Access**
Your iOS Provisioning Profile is associated with an App ID different from what you are trying to update to the Apple Store. Edit your provisioning profile in the [Apple Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/) and update the correct App ID. Regenerate the provisioning profile and use it in your next build for the warning to go away.

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement**
When you [create your certificate](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create) remember to select the 'Apple Push Notification service SSL' option. and repeat the certificate and mobile provisioning profile creation for your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have created the iOS Provisioning Profile from new account only but i am getting this error.